# Multiple self joins plus one inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I have two tables: `ck_startup` and `ck_price`. The price table contains the columns `cu_type`, `prd_type`, `part_cd`, `qty`, and `dllrs`. The startup table is linked to the price table through a one-to-many relationship on `ck_startup.prd_type_cd = ck_price.prd_type`.

The price table contains multiple entries for the same product/part/qty but under different customer types. Not all customer types have the same unique combination of those three values. I'm trying to create a query that will do two things:

1. Join some columns from `ck_startup` onto `ck_price` (description, and some additional values).
2. Join `ck_price` onto itself with a `dllrs` column for each customer type. So in total I would only have one instance of each unique key of product/part/qty, and a value in each customer's price column if they have one.

I've never worked with self joining tables, and so far I can only get records to show up where both customers have the same options available.

And because someone is going to demand I post sample code, here's the crappy query that doesn't show missing prices:

```
select pa.*, pac.dllrs from ck_price pa
join ck_price pac on pa.prd_type = pac.prd_type and pa.part_carbon_cd = pac.part_carbon_cd and pa.qty = pac.qty
where pa.cu_type = 'A' and pac.cu_type = 'AC';
```

**EDIT:** Here's sample data from the two tables, and how I want them to look when I'm done:

```
CK_STARTUP
+-----+-----------------+-------------+
| CD  |       DSC       | PRD_TYPE_CD |
+-----+-----------------+-------------+
| 3D  | Stuff           | SKD3        |
| DC  | Different stuff | SKD         |
| DN2 | Similar stuff   | SKD         |
+-----+-----------------+-------------+

CK_PRICE
+---------+-------------+---------+-----+-------+
| CU_TYPE | PRD_TYPE_CD | PART_CD | QTY | DLLRS |
+---------+-------------+---------+-----+-------+
| A       | SKD3        |       1 | 100 |    10 |
| A       | SKD3        |       1 | 200 |    20 |
| A       | SKD3        |       1 | 300 |    30 |
| A       | SKD         |       1 | 100 |    50 |
| A       | SKD         |       1 | 200 |   100 |
| AC      | SKD3        |       1 | 300 |    30 |
| AC      | SKD         |       1 | 100 |   100 |
| AC      | SKD         |       1 | 200 |   200 |
| AC      | SKD         |       1 | 300 |   300 |
| AC      | SKD         |       1 | 400 |   400 |
+---------+-------------+---------+-----+-------+

COMBO:
+----+-----------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+
| CD |       DSC       | PART_CD | QTY | DLLRS_A | DLLRS_AC |
+----+-----------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+
| 3D | Stuff           |       1 | 100 | 10      | null     |
| 3D | Stuff           |       1 | 200 | 20      | null     |
| 3D | Stuff           |       1 | 300 | 30      | 60       |
| DC | Different stuff |       1 | 100 | 50      | 100      |
| DC | Different stuff |       1 | 200 | 100     | 200      |
| DC | Different stuff |       1 | 300 | null    | 300      |
| DC | Different stuff |       1 | 400 | null    | 400      |
+----+-----------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Does ORacle have a full outer join?

Comment: Yes it does. Never used it. EDIT: switching this query to full outer join does not change the result set. For the record there are 423 records under 'A' and 384 records under 'AC'. The result set is 312 records.

Comment: try adding the where conditions to the on

Comment: Hmm... nope. Getting 11528 records back. That's basically the size of the table squared.

Comment: It's kinda hard to understand what you expect the query to return. Could you provide sample data from both tables and show us what output you are expecting?

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej - Sample tables added. I'm basically trying to get a pricing grid out of a "single column" data set. Joining the startup table onto the price one is less important than getting the self joins on the price table working.

Comment: @Logarr how many different values do you have in `CU_TYPE` column in `CU_PRICE` table? Can it change? If so, what you are trying to achieve is impossible, since you would have an unknown number of columns. `PIVOT` won't help either, since you have to provide a static list of values for it.

Comment: The possible values for CU_TYPE only changes if I make the change myself. This is going to be run manually in SQL Developer, so if the options for CU_TYPE change then I'm prepared to make the changes to my joins to reflect that.

Comment: If you get a second and are interested in learning more about Self Joins I posted a pretty good (albeit lengthy) answer to another user's question.  [Check it out if you want.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925971/self-join-vs-inner-join/32656064#32656064)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, take a look at below query and at the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT
          cs.cd, cs.dsc, cp.part_cd, cp.qty, cp.dllrs, cp.cu_type
        FROM ck_startup cs
          JOIN ck_price cp ON (cs.prd_type_cd = cp.prd_type_cd))
PIVOT (SUM(dllrs) AS dlllrs FOR (cu_type) IN ('A' AS a, 'AC' AS ac))
ORDER BY cd, qty
;
```

Output:

```
CD       DSC                  PART_CD     QTY   A_DLLLRS  AC_DLLLRS
-------- ----------------- ---------- ------- ---------- ----------
3D       Stuff                      1     100         10            
3D       Stuff                      1     200         20            
3D       Stuff                      1     300         30         30 
DC       Different stuff            1     100         50         50 
DC       Different stuff            1     200        100        100 
DC       Different stuff            1     300                   150 
DC       Different stuff            1     400                   200 
DN2      Similar stuff              1     100         50         50 
DN2      Similar stuff              1     200        100        100 
DN2      Similar stuff              1     300                   150 
DN2      Similar stuff              1     400                   200
```

It is not what you would expect, because I do not understand why you have different values in `DLLRS_AC` column that are in the `CK_PRICE` table? I mean, for example, why do you have `400` in last line of your output, not `200`? Why is this value doubled (as others are in `DLLRS_AC` column)?

If you are using Oracle 10g, you can achieve the same result using `DECODE` and `GROUP BY`, take a look:

```
SELECT
        cd,
        dsc,
        part_cd,
        qty,
        SUM(DECODE(cu_type, 'A', dllrs, NULL)) AS dllrs_a,
        SUM(DECODE(cu_type, 'AC', dllrs, NULL)) AS dllrs_ac
FROM (
  SELECT
    cs.cd, cs.dsc, cp.part_cd, cp.qty, cp.dllrs, cp.cu_type
  FROM ck_startup cs
    JOIN ck_price cp ON (cs.prd_type_cd = cp.prd_type_cd)
  )
GROUP BY cd, dsc, part_cd, qty
ORDER BY cd, qty;
```

Result is the same.

If you want to read more about pivoting, I recommend article by Tim Hall: [Pivot and Unpivot at Oracle Base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)

Comment: Whoops. I pasted in the wrong CK_PRICE table. I'll fix that up. Aside from that, it seems I'm working with Oracle 10g, so I don't have `pivot` capability...

Comment: @Logarr I've added another solution for 10g using `DECODE` function, please take a look and tell me if this is going to work for you.

Comment: Brilliant! I always forget that you can query the results of a sub-query. I also don't have much experience with the `DECODE` function. Thank you very much!